# java.time - Is there a function to find number of a specific day (day of week, or day of month) between two days?

Tags: java, java-time

So is there a function or something which you give two dates and a day of week **(ex. Saturday)** and it returns the number of Saturdays between the two dates?

The problem with trying to use `ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between` and dividing the result by **7** is that it won't work if you have something like **4** days **(because it's not a full week)**, or **10** days **(because it'll be counted as one week)**.

Another idea maybe to use a loop and check if a day is Saturday, but this way is inefficient and slow for large time ranges.

What about a similar function but rather than a day of week, it counts the occurrences of a day of month **(ex. 15th of any month)**, or a day of year **(ex. April 4th of any year)**.

If there are no such functions, what may be an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Take the difference of two dates in days and divide by 7, round down? Will this give the expected answer? For months it will be trickier, because months are not equal length. In that case it is probably the simplest to iterate all days and check if the match the give predicate (e.g. "is a Saturday")

Comment: "_Another idea maybe to use a loop and check if a day is Saturday, but this way is inefficient and slow for large time ranges_" – how large of time ranges are you expecting? I would think `from.datesUntil(then).filter(date -> date.getDayOfWeek() == SATURDAY).count()` would work fine for human-reasonable time spans.

Comment: It would be very unlikely to have a function that made such a very project specific idiosyncratic an API. For example, is there a function to return how many Tuesdays occur on a full Moon. No, but you could write one. You'll have to create an algorithm based on more primitive functions as mentioned in the last two comments.

Comment: @knittl dividing by 7 does work for days, I've used it, but the same idea can't work for months, or years (because of leap days).

Comment: @Slaw the time range may be over 5 years.

Comment: On my computer, using the code in my comment, it took only about 9 seconds to compute the number of Saturdays over 1,000,000 (one million) years. And that was a cold start through Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others commented, you need to write your own code. But *java.time* and Java Streams get you most of the way.

The `LocalDate::datesUntil` method generates a stream of `LocalDate` objects. Test each for its `DayOfWeek`. Collect the hits.

Something like this untested example code.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate start = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate then = today.plusDays( 177 ) ;
Stream < LocalDate > dates = start.datesUntil( then ) ;
List < LocalDate > saturdays = 
        dates
        .filter( 
            date -> 
                date
                .getDayOfWeek()
                .equals( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ) 
        )
        .collect( 
            Collectors.toList()
        )
;
```

You expressed a concern about efficiency. I suspect you are falling into the trap of premature optimization. Is your app really performing this operation thousands of times per minute all day? If not, performance is likely not a problem.

Always write simple straightforward code first. Then test empirically with the [Microbenchmarks Suite](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/230) and with a profiler to see if your concerns are valid.

Comment: I'm using ThreeTenABP (java.time back port  for android) and it looks like datesUnil method was added in Java 9 and it isn't available in ThreeTenBP.

Comment: @Azzam It would have been prudent to tag your question with [tag:android] and [tag:threetenbp]/[tag:threetenabp].

Comment: @AzzamAlsharafi Replace the stream with a while loop, incrementing the `LocalDate` each time with a call to `plusDays`. Add each hit to a `List`.